# Signin Sessions Helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

If you watch over any of Ryan Bates Authentication related Railscasts you'll see a recurring theme when creating sigin/signout functionality and I wanted to understand that a little bit more clearly.

```
def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
helper_method :current_user
```

For example usually in a session controller the create action will contain an assignment to the sessions hash such as `session[:user_id] = user.id` given that the variable user is set to an Active Record Object.

The above helper method is then used throughout the views to find the current signed in user.

However when signing out the destroy action contains only the line `session[:user_id] = nil`

My question is wouldn't `@current_user` also be needed to set to nil since it would be set to the previous User that was signed in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically after setting `session[:user_id] = nil` your controller will return so `@current_user` still being active doesn't matter.  You have to remember that `@current_user` only exists for that request, the next request that comes through is a new instance of that controller class.

You are right that if you did something like this:

```
def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  logger.debug current_user.inspect  # Current user is still set for this request
  redirect_to admin_url, notice => "You've successfully logged out."
end
```

You would see the user information in the log file, but normally you are doing a redirect right after clearing the session[:user_id] so that controller instance is done.

Comment: K thanks! Makes sense. So as soon as the page is redirected on the next request `@current_user` is loaded again but instead of it containing the user_id for the previously signed user its essentially   `@current_user = nil || User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]?`